# Does GPIO.gpio_function work?

Tags: gpio

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Checking%20function%20of%20GPIO%20channels/

says

gpio_function(channel)
Shows the function of a GPIO channel.
For example:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
func = GPIO.gpio_function(pin)
```

will return a value from:

```
GPIO.IN, GPIO.OUT, GPIO.SPI, GPIO.I2C, GPIO.HARD_PWM, GPIO.SERIAL, GPIO.UNKNOWN
```

When I try it I get a 1 digit number.  Has it ever worked as stated above ?

Comment: I don't use python so I don't have a definitive answer for you, but considering there are < 10 values there, how many digits were you expecting?  Put another way, did you try comparing that number to any of those *identifiers* to see if they are equivalent?  An identifier is the *name* of a variable or constant.  If I a call a variable or constant `SUPER.GREAT`, what kind of value is stored in it?  Is it a number?  A string?  Something else?  All caps are commonly used as identifiers for *constants* in many languages, BTW.  A constant has a value that does not change.  Like, for example, `3`.

Comment: +2 for reading the documentation. -1 for not understanding the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
print GPIO.IN, GPIO.OUT, GPIO.SPI, GPIO.I2C, GPIO.HARD_PWM, GPIO.SERIAL, GPIO.UNKNOWN
```

returns

```
1 0 41 42 43 40 -1
```

So these are inputs.

Comment: To elaborate: The digit you get returned is the state of the pin where 1=GPIO.IN, 0=GPIO.OUT, 41=GPIO.SPI, etc.